# How do I use relative paths and directories in php

Tags: php, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, relative-path

I have 200 sites that I support, they are all using:

```
<?php
Include ("/_include/config.php");
?>
```

But they are erroring out when hitting the page that has this include. What do I need to do to fix it?

I am assuming it is because of a relative path and the directory it is in and I get that, I just don't know how to fix it fast.

Windows 2008 R2
IIS 7.5
PHP 7

Thank you,

Comment: learn about namespacing as that is the best way to handle this

Comment: use `echo getcwd();` to print the current work directory. This is the directory the path is relative to. Make sure the config file exists

Answer (score 0):

To include another script relative to the path of the current script, a common solution is to combine the [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constant with the [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) function like so:

```
include dirname(__FILE__).'/_include/config.php';
```

You can also use `'..'` or nested `dirname` calls to traverse to parent directories:

```
include dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/_include/config.php';
// is equivalent to:
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../_include/config.php';
```

Comment: I agree on changing the default for all new sites but I need to figure it out for the existing 200. Is it a iis issue or is it an ini issue? I get the failed opening config.php file for inlcusion (include_path='c:\php\pear') error.

Comment: If memory serves me correctly I believe starting a path with a forward slash will reference the root of the file system on Windows. So `include '/_include/config.php'` would reference `C:\_include\config.php`. One hacky solution I can think of to avoid changing any code would be to create a [junction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx) from `C:\_include` to where the `_include` directory actually resides (assuming `_include` is a single directory shared amoung all the sites).

Comment: What would have changed in php 5.6 and php 7? With php 5.6 it still works but upgrading to 7 it no longer works.

Comment: I can't pinpoint what changed exactly or when but I am able to replicate the difference after downloading both PHP binaries for Windows. PHP 5.6 treats a path that starts with `/` as relative and PHP 7 treats it as absolute (C:\ on my system) when including another script. I cannot see any documentation for the change or an obvious php.ini setting. Personally I would bite the bullet and update all instances of the include with a search & replace tool to not include the proceeding `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Work with getcwd() function. This always returns the directorypath where the current called (not included) file is (exp. C:\xampp\htdocs). relative to that you can edit your includes:

```
include  getcwd() . "\include\config.php"; /* C:\xampp\htdocs\include\config.php */
```